# Snowflake session no longer exists. new login required to access the service for .NET connector

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are pulling data from Snowflake into my ASP.NET MVC 4.7.2 application using Snowflake .NET connector (`Snowflake.Data` 2.0.15) and running into an issue as outlined below.

The issue occurs only when there is no call from app to Snowflake for more than 4 hours.

> Session no longer exists. New login required to access the service. SqlState: , VendorCode: 390111

I understand this can be fixed by setting `CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE=True` which I guess is not supported by .NET ? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE` is supported for .NET driver and has been added since version [2.0.18](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Dot-NET-Driver-Release-Notes). See also [here](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/releases) for version 2.0.18.

The documentation for [parameters](https://docs.snowflake.com/sql-reference/parameters#client-session-keep-alive) though seems not being updated and that may cause the confusion.

I would suggest to use at least version 2.0.23 since it has some issues fixed for this parameter:

```
2.0.23
Fixed an issue where a .NET application would terminate for an unhandled exception when client_session_keep_alive=true.
 
2.0.22
Fixed an issue that caused applications that set CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE=true to hang when it closed the connection.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.. @Sergiu

We have upgraded our application to .Net version 4.7.2 very recently and latest version of Snowflake is no longer supported on .Net version 4.7.2.. Again now upgrading the whole application is a huge lift since we have many microservices which gets impacted..

Expecting any simple workaround, to fix this issue temporarily..

Comment: @RudreshKundur Where did you find the information about .NET framework 4.7.2 not being supported? We support `.NET Framework 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 6.0`! Have a look here on the [Readme](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net) page.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification..
We have one .net library (.Net Standard 2.0) which communicates with Snowflake.
Does this Snowflake 2.0.23 supports on .Net Standard 2.0. (its working on my local with some warning message (adding warning message in next comment)

That library communicates with the main application which is of .Net Version 4.7.2.

(please forgive if its a poor question)

Comment: WARNING: Package 'Snowflake.Data 2.0.23' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.